# Xcode to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, import

my classmate and I made a C++ Project in Xcode, however the Prof needs it in Visual Studio.
I have a PC with Visual Studio at home but I cant seem to be able to convert the Project. The option "clone code" doesnt work. I saw on the microsoft website that there should be an option to import Xcode Projects but i cant seem to find that in my Visual Studio.
Would copying the classes and code manually work? Im very new to programming. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you seen/followed this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/import-an-xcode-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: The fastest way is most likely to create a new VS project and add the source files to it.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you trying to use? There are versions of it, dating to 2003. Also, the edition (standard/professional/enterprise) of the visual studio might impact what features are enabled.